# STM32CubeIDE's post-build step to convert to hex or bin

Tags: stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm using the STM32CubeIDE for the project build but trying to do post build steps as a method to put the application checksum/crc into the .hex file.  I read that the below command should work with the STM32CubeIDE builder.

first to convert .elf to .bin
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -O binary main.elf main.tmp.bin

and then .bin to .hex after the checksum is done...
arm-none-eabi-objcopy -I binary -O ihex 
--change-addresses 0x08020000 main.bin hex2.tmp

but I get error that it's not a recognizable command...see attached image
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHYw0.png)

Am I missing a path variable or something?

Comment: It looks like you just typed your command in at a Windows command prompt - is that right? I would not expect that to work, since the GNU tools are almost certainly not in your `PATH`. However, setting up a CubeIDE post-build step would use the proper `PATH`, and so should work. (And does work, I've tried it.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can make this part of CubeIDE's build process, with some caveats.

Firstly, you can't just type these commands (e.g. for testing) into a Windows command prompt window. Your `PATH` environment variable will not include the directory where the GNU tools are stored. You'd need to manually add the correct paths to your `PATH`. You can see which directories CubeIDE uses by opening your project's `Properties` window, and going to `C/C++ Build -> Environment`.

[image]

Next, note that CubeIDE can automatically generate a `.bin` file for your program already. Go to `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> [Tool settings] -> MCU Post build outputs` and you can select `Convert to binary file`:

[image]

Lastly, you can enter one user-defined post-build step at `Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> [Build steps]`.

[image]

This would be the place to invoke whatever command generates and inserts the CRC. CubeIDE will use the correct path so you don't need to specify it here.

I don't think there is a way to add yet another post-build step, but a `.bin` file should be ok for programming. If you *really* need a `.hex` file you might have to make a script that does the CRC and final `objcopy` to achieve that, and call the script as your post-build step.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using a Windows system and trying to convert the .elf file to hex.
I did this using the following command:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy  -O ihex  LSM1x0A_SDK_LoRaWAN_Sigfox.elf  "LSM1x0A_SDK_LoRaWAN_Sigfox.hex"
```

- Remember to change the elf file name and the target hex file name.

In addition, if you need to execute a python script then you can combine multiple commands as follows:

```
arm-none-eabi-objcopy  -O ihex  LSM1x0A_SDK_LoRaWAN_Sigfox.elf  "LSM1x0A_SDK_LoRaWAN_Sigfox.hex" & cd D:/cf_firmwares/LRWN_dev/LSM1x0A_dev/Projects/NUCLEO-WL55CC/Applications/LoRaWAN_Sigfox/LSM100A/STM32CubeIDE/Release & ls & python D:/cf_firmwares/LRWN_dev/LSM1x0A_dev/Utilities/1_SJITools/1_FW_Merge_Tool/main.py
```

Above command, I tried to following stuff:

- convert elf to hex
- moving to a new directory
- check what is there in that directory
- executing a python script

Observation:

- Post-build commands might be executed in a random manner
- Works like a Ubuntu terminal

result
[image: demo_cmd]

[image]

Hope this will help